# locate with color

Tags: locate

I used `locate` binary many time to search something on my 1TB HDD.

Most of the time, I got many result and I have to read each line to get what exactly I'm looking for.

It would be great if the `locate` can output the matched pattern with color ( just like grep --color)

Is there any way to do so for `locate` command ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to write a simple **shell script** which combines `locate` and `grep`:

Create a file somewhere in your $PATH (e.g. `/usr/local/bin/clocate`) with

```
#!/bin/sh
locate --regex "$1" | grep --color=auto "$1"
```

then make it executable, e.g.

```
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/clocate
```

and use it like `locate`. The script does only accept one pattern.

Another way is to use a **shell function**: If you are using `bash` as your shell, you can add to your `$HOME/.bashrc` the following line:

```
clocate() { locate --regex  "$1" | grep --color=auto "$1"; }
```

You need to rerun bash or re-source your `.bashrc` before you can the new command.

Please note the `--regex` option for `locate`. You need to write `.*` instead of `*`  to match any number of characters.

Comment: To replace current locate could add `alias locate=clocate` after that function on `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 0):

This for two patterns
The first pattern in the command line, the second when invited.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Type the second argument."
read constraint
locate -i "$1" | grep -i $(echo "$constraint") |grep -i --color=auto -e $(echo "$1") -e $(echo "$constraint")
exit
```